# Can you use glmmTMB to simultaneously model offsets and zero-inflation?

Tags: mixed-model, glmm, zero-inflation, overdispersion, glmmtmb

I'm currently modelling microbial data, with multiple samples and groups of samples. Two problems arise with my data: 1) The data is zero-inflated and dispersed (large variation); 2) Each sample has a different number of counts, leading to biased results based on sample-count size. To account for these problems, I tried modelling my data using a ZINB model with the glmmTMB package, using the 'Offset' argument to model total sample count and by specifying a 'ziformula' based on the structure of my data. However, while reading the manual it specifies that "Offset terms will automatically be dropped from the conditional effects formula when using ~".

Is there any way to account for zero-inflation, over-dispersion, and unequal sample-depth using a ZINB within glmmTMB, or should I look into other methods? My model currently has two random effects and 1 fixed effect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**tl;dr** as far as I can tell at this point,

```
 glmmTMB(formula=<...>+offset(log(sampling_effort)),
         ziformula = ~.,
         family=nbinom2,
         data=<...>)
```

should do what you want. (1) `ziformula` specifies zero-inflation.  (2) The offset term in the conditional model (`formula`) adjusts for sampling effort; as I understand your context, you *shouldn't need any adjustment for effort/sample depth in the zero-inflation part of the model* (since it describes structural zeros, which will always be observed as zero regardless of sampling effort). (3) `family=nbinom2` takes care of other sources of overdispersion.  [You might want to alternately consider `nbinom1`, which specifies $\textrm{Var} \propto \mu$ rather than $\textrm{Var} = \mu + \mu^2/k$.]

---

This is an interesting question both from the statistical and the implementation point of view.

Implementation: you can add offsets to zero-inflation terms, you just can't do it via `.`.  For example something like

```
 glmmTMB(y~x,
         family=nbinom2,
         zi=~x+offset(log(w)))
```

should work fine.  It's only if you try to use `zi = ~ .` to match the conditional formula in a lazy way that the offset gets dropped.

Statistics: I question a couple of your premises.

- First of all, it's not immediately obvious that different numbers of counts should lead to biased results; it's important to know what the source of the differences is - i.e. large natural variations in density, or variations in searching/capture effort?
- Second, you have to think carefully about the form of the offset. Using `log(effort)` as the offset with a log-link zero-inflation term (the only choice at present) will mean that the probability of an observation being a **structural** zero will be proportional to the effort, i.e. $\log(p_z) = ... + \log(e) \to p_z \propto e$.  In general a complementary log-log link (with log(effort) as the offset) is more appropriate for detection probabilities, as that makes the *hazard* of finding something proportional to effort. However, if you're really trying to model structural zeros I question whether search effort should influence this part of the model at all ...

---

Based on the comments, I think this question may be based on a (reasonable) misunderstanding of `?glmmTMB`, which currently reads

> `ziformula`: ... *Offset terms will automatically be dropped from the
>             conditional effects formula when using ‘~.’*

This warning applies **only** to the zero-inflation formula: the conditional formula (`formula`) argument isn't modified at all, it's only the zero-inflation version of the formula (and, as discussed above, you can include an offset in the zero-inflation part of the model if you really want to, by writing out the formula explicitly).  Thus if you follow the fairly standard procedure of adding `+ offset(log(sampling_effort))` to `formula` then the conditional mean number of counts will be proportional to effort (assuming a [default] log-link model for the counts).

In hopes of clarifying this I've tried editing this statement: is the following clearer?

> Specifying `~.` will set the right-hand side of the zero-inflation formula identical to the right-hand side of the main (conditional effects)
>   formula; terms can also be added or subtracted. **Offset terms
>   will automatically be dropped from the conditional effects formula when using `~.`**

(Hmmm, now that I read this over it doesn't seem much better ...) Feel free to comment (or suggest clearer wording) here, or at https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues ...

Comment: Based on this, it appears it wouldn't be possible to model the effect of effort on counts. I was hoping to use the offset argument as a scaling-factor approximation for effort. Is it at all possible to inverse the relationship of offset in a case like this, @Ben Bolker? Would multiplying with a large constant (e.g. 1000) all the proportions of counts as a function of effort (count/ sample effort) work? These types of problems involving structural zeros are common in gene-marker and microbial studies, and I think a solution/guide to this could greatly enhance the versatility of the package.

Comment: To clarify, I'm most concerned with modelling my data while correcting for the differences in sample-effort - so far, this is the only part I'm unable to account for with my model.

Comment: Thank you @Ben Bolker! Your answer is very clear - this is definitely worth trying. What I will try to do is to model `sampling_effort` as an offset like you suggested and observe whether or not the model converges.